# Trying to escapeHtml Characters with Jsondeserializer in spring boot, But when ever it is persisting html escaping is happening more than once

Tags: java, spring-boot, xss, json-deserialization, html-escape-characters

lets consider this scenario.
1.I have created a deserializer class

2.used JsonDeserilizer anotation in POJO class.

----------up to now everything is going good----------

when request come to controller which accepts POJO. 
    -- here one deserialization is happening 
Again if we send this same POJO to another method then 
    -- then here also deserialization is happening(which i don't want)

Any Suggestion or help it would save my time.